# Convert date string to another language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to change the order of a date string and then change the month language through code. I've added below string which is a example of the string.

```
March 13, Friday, 19:45 CET
```

However i want to change this dynamically to something like

```
10. Marts kl. 19:45
```

Here you can see i have changed march to marts which is march in my language and then i've rewritten the string. How can i programmatically change the first string to the expected string?

Comment: Have you tried using a regex match?

Comment: Hi Peter, could you please tell us which language the sample is being converted to? I'm guessing Marts is March translated. no idea about kl though

Comment: March 13 is March 10? Where the hell do you live? ;)

Comment: @DarkMouse, it is Danish. How can he not provide this information?

Comment: The answer would be the same for any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way. Since javascript returns a number for each day/month they can easly be orverwritten inside an array ( just keep in mind that javascript days/weeks starts with 0 )

```
function custom_date() {
    var today = new Date();
    var custom_months = [ "Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" ];
    var custom_days = [ "mandag", "tirsdag", "onsdag", "torsdag", "fredag", "lørdag", "søndag" ];
    var date = today.getDate() + ". " + custom_months[ today.getMonth() ] + " " + custom_days[ today.getDay() ];
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
    return  date + " " +time;
}

console.log( custom_date() );
```

Right now `custom_date` returns a string like **15. Marts mandag 19:34**. Of course, you can edit `custom_months` and `custom_days` following your needs.

You can live see the result on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0k11d2d/) ( open the console to see the result )